# Call a batch file and wait for it to finish

Tags: batch-file

I do not have not much [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) experience and want to run one as a time scheduled task.

The script essentially `call`s two other `.bat` files:

```
@echo off
call "%~dp0\1.bat"
call "%~dp0\2.bat"
shutdown /s /t 60
```

I want to shutdown the PC after `2.bat` has completed,
but I do not know if `2.bat` waits for `1.bat` to be done. Similarly with `shutdown` waiting for `2.bat` to be done, or do they run simultaneously?

If so is there a way to wait for the previous script to complete?

Comment: Sorry my English is worse than my batch knowledge... Yes. I want to run the first script to be completed then run the second script and wait to be completed and then do a shutdown.

Comment: that is what will happen here, unless your batch files calls other executables which it does not control. You can also chain them `call "%~dp01.bat" && call "%~dp02.bat" && shutdown /s /t 60` this will then only execute the next command if the previous was successful (`errorlevel=0`)